# problema con un objeto xmlHttpRequest, como retornar la respuesta?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Buen dia, requiero asesoria en AJAX: tengo una función que por medio de un objeto XMLHttpRequest hace una petición a otro archivo php y me retorna un listado, quiero que al llamar a esta función  filtrarxYear() me retorne el valor de "xhttp.responseText.

Tal como lo tengo en el return en la ultima linea de la función no me retorna nada, según entiendo porque estoy retornando una respuesta que aun no llega.
Quisiera saber si es posible lo que quiero y como hacerlo para no tener que llamar a las otras funciones dentro de la función dela propiedad "onload"

```
function filtrarxYear(){
    var xhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();    
    xhttp.onload=function(){
       var lista=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
       //console.log(lista);
    }
    xhttp.open("POST","../templates/controladorHistory.php");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("peticionLista");
    return xhttp.responseText; //lo que quiero retornar
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Buenas te paso un ejemplo muy sencillo de como hacer un request POST a un archivo mediante ajax usando jquery.
Tene en cuenta que el archivo controladorHistory devuelve usando echo y no return.

Archivo HTML

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js" integrity="sha256-HwWONEZrpuoh951cQD1ov2HUK5zA5DwJ1DNUXaM6FsY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script>  
  $.ajax({
    url: 'controladorHistory.php',
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);      
    }
  });
</script>
```

ARCHIVO PHP (controladorHistory.php)

```
<?php

echo "Respuesta de prueba";

?>
```